# Ruby does not write valid UTF-8 to file?

Tags: ruby, encoding, jruby

We use a CMS, which is a real pain to use when it comes to encoding, but still I need to generate a Structure for it.

I set: `Encoding.default_internal` to UTF-8, I tried with `# Encoding: UTF-8` and I wrote the files with `File.open("filename", "w:UTF-8")` but I always got something like this:

```
DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xF6 0x6A 0xE4 0x6B in Entity, line: 7DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Empty string supplied as input
```

The file contains `öäü`, and, if I remove them, it works like expected.

If I use the Notepad++ function "Convert to UTF-8 without BOM" and write the "Umlaute (öäü)" manually in it, it works.

Changing the values to HTML entities like `&ouml;`, is no option, as they would appear this way in the backend.

PS: It's written with JRuby.

Comment: Did your XML file have the proper encoding at the header line?: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: yes, i forget to mention that. I dont even generate the XML i just copy a working default "template" and replace the title

Comment: How do you replace the title? Could the XML be mangled after the replace? Have you tried running the XML through something like [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) to verify the process and the XML data separately? Is the text being inserted inside a CDATA block, and have the values been converted to an encoded format or are they still raw?

Comment: I have the template in an string, then just `.gsub('{TITLE}', current[:title])`, and yes i tried `current[:title].encode("UTF-8)`. But thx for the hint with xmllint, it replaced the "Umlaute" with `&#xF6;` and similar, which seems to get interpreted right from the backend which automatically fixes the page then. 1 title is in CDATA and one without, doesnt seem to make any difference, also i encode the strings explicitly to UTF-8

Comment: The message `Bytes: 0xF6 0x6A 0xE4 0x6B` suggests that the input is in iso-8859-1 encoding. How are you reading the input? You might need to do something like `File.open("input_file"), "r:iso-8859-1"`, or handle the encoding with [`encode`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode) (or possibly [`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-force_encoding)).

Comment: thanks for the tipp, i will look into this tomorrow. Btw, what ruby tells me if i check which `.encoding` the template string has its "Windows-1252"

Comment: @seta [`Windows-1252`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is a superset of iso-8859-1, so that would make sense. If the encoding is already set you probably only need to use `encode` to convert it to utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you are modifying the XML, but if you're doing it with regular expressions and `gsub` you're walking on the wild side.

I highly recommend using an XML parser/generator to modify the XML. XML is a strict specification, especially when dealing with non-ASCII characters, and a good parser/generator will take that stuff into account when inserting text.

For example, using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org):

```
# encoding: utf-8

require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<root>
  <atextnode>content</atextnode>
</root>
EOT

atextnode = doc.at('atextnode')
atextnode.content = "öäü"
puts doc.to_xml
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <atextnode>&#xF6;&#xE4;&#xFC;</atextnode>
</root>
```

Changing the output encoding to UTF-8:

```
puts doc.to_xml(encoding: 'UTF-8')
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <atextnode>öäü</atextnode>
</root>
```

Comment: Sure this would be cool, but the tool actually has to handle all kind of templates and should not be limited to XML, but maybe i can borrow some converting functions from nokogiri ^^

Comment: Nokogiri ONLY parses XML and HTML. You won't get it to parse/generate anything else because it relies on libXML. It's easy enough to sniff out what type of file something is, and conditionally branch on that, allowing Nokogiri to be used for just the stuff it's designed to do.

Comment: With borrow i ment like searching there source for what they are doing as my `str.gsub('ä','&#xE4;').gsub("ü",'&#xFC;').gsub('ä','&#xF6;').force_encoding('Windows-1252').encode("UTF-8")` not really does anything that would work... Also "use this library" is really not the answer i was thinking about. Nokogiri has heavy depencies. Still thx for your help

Comment: What heavy dependencies? libXML is a standard install, or easily installed on *nix boxes and easily added to other OSes. If you're using JRuby, I wouldn't be surprised if you had to install libXML to get Java working.

Comment: the tool runs on windows machines only and i need to pack it into a jar later on. for this purpose each depency is one to much. But yeah i actually thought there are more. Still, your tip solved my problem, the &# encoding gets fixed from the CMS, it works for me for now. So thx